# Highcharts multiple series from JSON with different style depending on serie name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to style different series on Highcharts depending on JSON names.
Is that possible?

```
$.each(names, function (i, name) {

    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?',    function (data) {

        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data,
            if(name=="GOOG") dashStyle: 'longdash',
        };
```

[Something like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsx7y.png)

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiskolini/eqc0jqof/)

Answer (score 0):

This configuration can be done simply add a condition inside `seriesOptions` object:

```
seriesOptions[i] = {
        name: name,
        data: data,
        dashStyle: (name=="GOOG"? 'longdash': ''),
      };
```